# CRUD operations Cassandra mappers vs prepared statement

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I would like some help defining the difference between the use of the object mapper of datastax for Cassandra and the common solution of using prepared statements. Instead of the fact that the code will be cleaner with mapping the objects to POJO classes are there any other advantages regarding performance ect. . Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Object Mapper uses prepared statements under the hood (see [source code](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-mapping/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/mapping/Mapper.java)), so performance-wise there shouldn't be very big performance difference. You need to pay attention to setting options, like `saveNullFields` (if you save `null`s, then the thombstones could be generated that could affect read performance). Also, for high-performance writes you may need to look to async versions of Mapper opperations.

Also, you need to make sure that you're not creating `MappingManager` more than once - it's also thread-safe like `Session` object.